# Does Python's subprocess print colorized output?

Tags: python, subprocess, alias, ls

I'm working on a customized version of `ls`. In this customized version, called `lf` (list fancy), I simply created an alias to `ls` with the flags `-AbcFghkLst`. However, I want more functionality out of this without memorizing what each flag does. For instance, `lf -n` would sort by name or `lf -c` would sort by time created. In order to overcome this task, I am using `argparse` for flags.

Here lies the problem. The alias `lf` calls `ls` and prints colorized output to the console. `subprocess.run()` prints bland output to the console. Is there a way to capture the colorized output through `subprocess.run()`? If not, is there a way to add flag behavior to `lf`?

Here is an example of the code currently.

```py
import argparse
import subprocess

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A fancy version of ls')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
group.add_argument('-n', '--name', action='store_true', help='Sort entries by name')
group.add_argument('-c', '--created', action='store_true', help='Sort entries by creation date')

args = parser.parse_args()

ls = ['ls']

flags = '-AbcFghkLs'  # Desired output before sorting flag.

if args.name:
    flags += 'l'
    ls.extend([flags])

elif args.created:
    ls.extend([flags])

else:
    ls.extend(['-AbcFghkLst'])
    
subprocess.run(ls)
```

And this is what it currently looks like after executing.
[image: The first lf is an alias to the unix command and the second command calls ls from a Python script. Notice the change in directory color between the two.]

Comment: Without the `--color` argument, ls doesn't colorize the output.  (I suspect your `lf` alias is chaining into another alias that does use the `--color` argument.)

Comment: I'm surprised I missed that when looking over documentation. However, after testing, I cannot pass `--` arguments to `ls`. I get the error `ls: illegal option -- -`. I also realized that `ls` was aliased to `ls -G` which adds color but I don't see why.

Comment: What is the full command which generates that error?

Comment: `ls --color=always` generates that error. I also thought `--group-directories-first` would be nice, but that flag causes the same error.

Comment: What os and version are you using?  And what flavor of ls?  (This should be in the manpage)

Comment: macOS Big Sur Version 11.5.1. By flavor, do you mean `ls(1)`?

Comment: I meant "flavor" as it applies to the various linux distros.  But you're using macOS, so it's irrelevant.  Forget I said it.  On your system, what does the man page say about color?  Is `--color` the option name, or is it something else?

Comment: On macOS Catalina, indeed there are no double-dash options.  `-G` is the color option.  I assume Big Sur is the same.